# ¿Cómo es que se realiza esto?, soy nuevo con css y no consigo realizar las transiciones

Tags: css, html5, css3

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: black;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}

#box1:hover {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#box2:hover {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}

#box3:hover {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}

#box4:hover {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transition: 4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="box1">Caja 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">Caja 2</div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">Caja 3</div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">Caja 4</div>
</div>
```

Dados el siguiente código HTML y CSS base, crear las transiciones
necesarias para pasar del estado inicial al final, aplicando las
siguientes transformaciones:

- Rotar los elementos 270grados
- Intercambiar las posiciones de las cajas 1 y 2, 3 y 4
- Cambiar el tamaño de 100px a 50px
- Cambiar el color de fondo de azul a rojo
- Cambiar el color del texto de negro a amarillo
- Cambiar el tamaño de letra de 20px a 18px.

En realidad solo busco saber como es que se hace el cambio de posiciones entre cajas, es decir, que al pasar el puntero por la caja1 esta se mueva hacia donde se encuentra la caja2 y así...

Comment: ¿Es un intercambio _aleatorio_ o es _del 1 al 2, del 2 al 3..._?

Comment: @padaleiana según entiendo el intercambio de posiciones es [1 al 2 y 2 al 1] y [3 al 4 y 4 al 3]. Lo que no me queda claro es porque tiene que ser en el `hover`, no veo que diga que debe disparar la animación.

Comment: @Marcos no necesariamente en el hover y el orden puede ser aleatorio

Comment: si le dieras a container `display:flex` podrías jugar con la propiedad `order` para carmbiarlos de orden

Comment: @ffflabs y como aplicaria el order o en donde?

Comment: Tal como te dijeron, `order` es una _propiedad_. ¡Revisa la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/order)!

Comment: Le pones a cada box un order distinto. Es una propiedad tal como font-size o color

Answer (score -1):

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```css
.box { width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 10px 5px; padding: 15px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; font-size: 20px; background: blue; color: black; }

#box1:hover { transform: rotate(270deg); transition: 1s ease-in-out; }

#box2:hover { transform: rotate(270deg); transition: 2s ease-in-out; }

#box3:hover { transform: rotate(270deg); transition: 3s ease-in-out; }

#box4:hover { transform: rotate(270deg); transition: 4s ease-in-out; }
```

Espero que te haya servido

## Javi17mod

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Por aquí no solemos responder haciendo tareas de clase, puesto que copiar y pegar no sirve para aprender. Por otro lado, si vas a responder te recomiendo que añadas una explicación de por qué tu código responde a la pregunta! Una respuesta de solo código no es correcta. Y si hubieses añadido la explicación verías que tu respuesta tampoco responde a la pregunta en realidad, puesto que me da la sensación de que tu código no reordena de ninguna manera las cajas. De hecho, parece que lo único que has hecho es pegar el código de la pregunta con un formato ligeramente diferente...